# Checkbox validation repetition problem with JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

There are a few problems with validating a checkbox with a jQuery. Validation is with the following code. But the problem is - every time I click the submit button, it is repeated. How do I stop it?

2. I want to remove the validation error whenever I click on the checkbox.
3. The user has to select Atlist One or two checkboxes, how to apply this condition?

[image]

```js
$('form.checkout').on('submit', function () {
if (!$('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $("input:checkbox").parent().after("<span class='error'>This field requerd....</span>");
} 

else {
    $("input:checkbox").parent().next(".error").remove();
}
});
```

```html
<p id="checkout_terms">
    <label class="label-for-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
        <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions</span>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1" />
</p>
```

Comment: please share the relevant HTML in the post

Comment: Please check my update please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the error every time, and only add it back if the checkbox isn't checked. You don't need an if/else condition.

```
// Form submission
$('form.checkout').on('submit', function () {

    let valid = true;

    // Validate all checkboxes in the form
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').each(function () {

        // Start by removing any previous error
        removeCheckboxError(this);

        // Add a new error if the checkbox is unchecked
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().after('<span class="error">This field is required...</span>');
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    
    // Only allow the form to submit if all checkboxes were valid
    return valid;
});

// Remove error from a checkbox when clicked
$('form.checkout input:checkbox').click(function () {
    removeCheckboxError(this);
});

// Reusable function to remove errors
function removeCheckboxError(checkbox) {
    $(checkbox).parent().next('.error').remove();
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v2dnubox/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted your code. Solve my first problem. Can you help me with problems number two and three, please?

Comment: Excellent. But after clicking on the checkbox, the error is not removed. Where is the problem?

Comment: @MaryXNabors Check the link I put at the bottom of the post. It should remove. If not, there is something else happening in your code or your HTML is different maybe, in which case you should post your full form HTML and the JS you have.

Comment: I checked it. Works well in HTML. But there is a problem with woocommerce. But I fixed it differently. Thank you very much.

I am facing a few more problems in this regard. I have posted about this on stackoverflow. But did not get a response. Please help me? Shall I share the link here?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code where you can read the number of checked checkboxes and show or hide error accordingly.
Instead of submitting form and validating, use button click event and submit form when no error.

```js
var numOfReqCheckbox = 1; // number of checkboxes required
var errorHtml = "<span class='error'>This field requerd....</span>";
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
  var numOfCheckedCheckbox = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
if (numOfCheckedCheckbox < numOfReqCheckbox) {
    $("#checkout_terms").append(errorHtml);
} else {
    $("#checkout_terms .error").remove();
    $('form.checkout').submit();//submit form
}
});
```

```css
.error {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="checkout">
<p id="checkout_terms">
    <label class="label-for-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
        <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions</span>
   </label>
   <label class="label-for-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
        <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions</span>
</label>
   <label class="label-for-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
        <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions</span>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1" />
</p>
<input type="button" value=" Submit " id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you need make some HTML changes, like modify submit button type as "button" instead of "submit" and error message html should be outside `p`